# How to run angulardart application?

Tags: dart, webstorm, angular-dart

- I just download andgularjs dart tutorial from [angulardart.org](http://angulardart.org) . It provides me some tutorials, but I couldn't able to run those tutorials.
- I am using webStorm IDE to run those application. when I am trying to run the application, I am getting following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7FuR.png)

- I couldn't find package folder with in web root folder in that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to run `pub upgrade`. WebStorm provides this action in the context menu of the `pubspec.yaml` file, also if you open the `pubspec.yaml` file in the WebStorm editor links for `pub` actions are shown in the top-left corner of the editor. Alternatively you can run `pub run` from the command line of your project directory if the path is configured properly on your system so the command is found.